# Service 'listener' failed to build : docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to compose this .yml file

```
services:
  cedr_manager:
    container_name: cedr
    build:
      context: ./cedr_manager
      args:
        api_port: 8001
        project_domain_id: default
        user_domain_id: default
        openstack_user: demo
        openstack_pass: secret
        auth_url: "http://10.0.2.15/identity"
        openstack_tenant: admin
        kibana_url: "http://10.20.0.3:80"
        elasticsearch_url: "http://10.20.0.3:9200"
        http_proxy: ""
        https_proxy: ""
    volumes:
      - /mnt/cedr_db:/mnt/cedr_db
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    # this adds to /etc/hosts
    extra_hosts:
      - "pv:192.168.101.8"
  listener:
    container_name: listener
    build:
      context: ./listener
      args:
        host: 10.0.2.15
        port: 5672
        cedr_host: 10.0.2.15
        username: stackrabbit
        password: c7d4cfa3a3881a1a9c43
        http_proxy: "http://10.0.2.15"
        https_proxy: "https://10.0.2.15"
```

It's throwing an error that I am not able to solve. I update my python and pip but still, it throws the same. Any help would be appreciated.

The error looks like this

fetch http://dl- 
cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main: DNS lookup 
error
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.c51f8f92.tar.gz: No such file or 
directory
fetch http://dl- 
cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community: DNS 
lookup error
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.d09172fd.tar.gz: No such file or 
directory
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
build-base (missing):
required by: world[build-base]
linux-headers (missing):
required by: world[linux-headers]
py-pip (missing):
required by: world[py-pip]
python (missing):
required by: world[python]
python-dev (missing):
required by: world[python-dev]
ERROR: Service 'listener' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c 
apk add --update     python     python-dev     py-pip     build-base
linux-headers' returned a non-zero code: 5

```
The Docker File looks like this

FROM alpine:3.5
MAINTAINER Mirantis admin@mirantis.com

ARG http_proxy=""
ARG https_proxy=""
ARG host=192.168.0.3
ARG port=5673
ARG cedr_host=10.20.0.3
ARG username=nova
ARG password=8eLqY7li

#set proxy
ENV http_proxy $http_proxy https_proxy $https_proxy

RUN apk add --update \
    python \
    python-dev \
    py-pip \
    build-base \
    linux-headers

ADD . /listener_code
WORKDIR /listener_code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN sed -i -e "s/\${host}/$host/g" -e "s/\${port}/$port/g" -e "s/\${username}/$username/g" \
    -e "s/\${password}/$password/g" -e "s/\${cedr_host}/$cedr_host/g" listener.conf

# unset proxy
ENV http_proxy="" https_proxy=""
CMD python notify.py --config listener.conf
```

Comment: What does the dockerfile for listener look like? There's a few issues that could be affecting this: First, you're getting DNS errors and no file errors for alpine, so something might be causing problems with that. This issue (https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/155) suggests that might be a problem on alpine's end - you could try bumping to 3.7 to see if that helps. Second, the last line that is failing is trying to install a lot at once. Try installing each package on its own and you can isolate which package(s) is causing problems.

Comment: I added the docker file too now..please have a look

Comment: Sorry, but that looks fine to me. There is an issue on docker-alpine https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/55 that might have some help. I would suggest bumping to 3.7 or latest (`FROM alpine:3.7` or `FROM alpine:latest`) to see if that fixes it. It seems like an issue with the alpine repository, so if it's not important that you are locked to 3.5, 3.7 might have this issue fixed. Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't change anything, I tried 3.7 too!!

Comment: Check the issue I linked, you could try manually adding the repo links https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/55#issuecomment-162470199. Other than that, I'm out of ideas. Sorry.